# MUX/DMUX Driving a reed relay, output is coming even after the transistor is off

Tags: circuit-design, relay, bjt, simulation, multiplexer

I am driving a relay using a a MUX/DMUX it's P/N is [TMUX1308](https://www.ti.com/product/TMUX1308#design-development). The relay used is [9011-05-11](https://www.cotorelay.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/9011_series_reed_relay_datasheet.pdf).

The MUX/DMUX Enable pin is active low. What I observed in simulation is even after connecting the EN to Vcc using a pull up resistor the relay output is still coming.

I modeled the relay using a voltage-controlled switch. Please see the switch spec below.

[image]

Please see my circuit diagram and simulation results below. May I know where I went wrong?

Circuit Diagram
[image]

Output waveforms:

[image]

Comment: interesting  application for an analog mux. Not sure why you would chose that method, but it works. Is there a reason why a more pedestrian 4051 ic wouldn’t do much the same? I can’t see a problem in the simulation. Where precisely is it?

Comment: I am getting output even after disabling the Analog MUX.This MUX EN pin is active low.I connected it to Vcc using a pull up resistor,but still O/P is coming.

Comment: Try a 100 k pull down on VF3.

Comment: @Andyaka,Thank you.It is working fine now.May I know what is the issue.Missing the load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a 100 k pull down on VF3

> *@Andyaka,Thank you. It is working fine now. May I know what is the
> issue. Missing the load?*

Basically, without a load on the output of a switch that goes open circuit, there is nothing to collapse the voltage to 0 volts. Hence, you need some form of light load to entice the simulator to do the proper thing. If you look at the definition of your switch, it open-circuits to 1 GΩ and, with no load on the output node, you will still see 5 volts. If you used a 1 GΩ load you would probably see 2.5 volts.